# I need removelistener before ChangeNotifier disposed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

For example, i am call the `controller.dispose()` when page dispose, i also have to call the `controller.removeListener`?

```
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_listener);
  }

  void _listener() {
    print(_controller.text);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // _controller.removeListener(_listener); //It is a must？
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I see `ChangeNotify` source code about dispose

```
  @mustCallSuper
  void dispose() {
    assert(_debugAssertNotDisposed());
    _listeners = null;
  }
```

I think is cleared listener, i am not need to call the removeListener method. But somebody tell me i need call the reamoveListener method before dispose method. I feel confused and want someone to tell me i am right or wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just called

```
_controller.dispose();
```

you don't need to call _controller.removeListener(_listener);